# how to print the real QProcess arguments list as the QProcess excute them

Tags: qt, qprocess

How can i see in QProcess the real argument list it is processing?
for debuging , i do print the QStringList before i pass its to myProcess->start(program, arguments);
is there build in debugging option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process created by QProcess will see exactly the argument list you are passing to QProcess::start(). What you see when you print the QStringList passed to QProcess::start() is what the new process will see in its `argv[]` argument of main() (except for the program executable path, which is prepended as `argv[0]`.

If I misunderstood your question, please feel free to comment.